# How to get jquery dialog box to close after one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My dialog box only closes after two clicks and not one. I am not sure why it won't close on the first button click. Does the dialog box need to be hidden? I tried dialog.dialog.hide(); as well right after close, but that gives me no luck. This is what I have for my dialog.

```js
var dialog = $('<p>Cannot post. </p>').dialog({
  height: 150,
  width: 300,
  buttons: {
    "Ok": function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      dialog.dialog('close');
      $(this).display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `.dialog` isn't part of jquery - which library are you using?  jquery-ui? bootstrap? your own code?

Comment: jquery ui 1.11.4

Comment: @JDoe seems to close on first click: https://jsfiddle.net/aohd6vpL/1/

Comment: The correct method to close the dialog is `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "close" );` http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close - this will do more than just "hide" the dom elements, eg it will remove the modal background for you.   Worth looking at the examples (eg the add user one) in https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form where they provide the source

Comment: Try  $(this).dialog('close');  You're reinvoking the dialog with dialog.dialog().  You don't need the display = 'none.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/eo4z5gaj/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var dialog = $('<p>Cannot post. </p>').dialog({
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
      "Ok": function(event) {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It's better to refernce `$(this)` for `.dialog()`. Essentially they are the same.

If this code is still requiring two clicks of "Ok", then you should look at your browser or console. Code above works with single click in FireFox.

You may also consider: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/eo4z5gaj/8/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var dialog = $('<div>', {
    title: "Error"
  }).html("<p>Cannot Post.</p>").dialog({
    height: 160,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
      "Ok": function(event) {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.